# Optimize distance for a flight path PHP

Tags: php, geo

I try to optimize the distance from a flight path of a glider. I have GPS fixes every 3 seconds (latitude, longitude, altitude). So i now have all the fixes in an array:

```
//This is an example of a fix
$fixes[0]['lat'] = '4710789N'; 
$fixes[0]['lon'] = '00724859E';
$fixes[0]['altitude'] = '00386'; //meters 

//and another fix
$fixes[1]['lat'] = '4710899N'; 
$fixes[1]['lon'] = '00724965E';
$fixes[1]['altitude'] = '00392'; //meters
    .
    .
    .
    .
//and the rest of ~3000 fixes
```

The longitude and latitude of the fixes are actually in a DM format. So for better calculation with them i convert them with this function to decimal format:

```
function DMStoDecimal($DMS){

    $isLat = false;

    if(substr($DMS, 7, 1) == "N" || substr($DMS, 7, 1) == "S"){
        $isLat = true;
    }



    if($isLat){
        $deg = substr($DMS, 0, 2);
        $minutes = substr($DMS, 2, 2);
        $minutes .= "." . substr($DMS, 4, 3);

        $sign = "";

        if(substr($DMS, 7, 1) == "N"){
            $sign = "-";
        }

    }else{
        $deg = substr($DMS, 0, 3);
        $minutes = substr($DMS, 3, 2);
        $minutes .= "." . substr($DMS, 5, 3);

        $sign = "";

        if(substr($DMS, 8, 1) == "E"){
            $sign = "-";
        }

    }

    $minutesDecimal = (float)$minutes / 60;

    $result = $deg + $minutesDecimal;

    return $sign . $result;

}
```

And with this function, i can calculate the distance between two fixes:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    if (($lat1 == $lat2) && ($lon1 == $lon2)) {
        return 0;
    }else{

        $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);

        if ($unit == "K") {
            return ($miles * 1.609344);
        } else if ($unit == "N") {
            return ($miles * 0.8684);
        } else {
            return $miles;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot calculate the distance between every fix and summarize them because there are some rules how the distance for a flight is calculated. For a flight, i can only use 6 legs (1 start point, 5 Turnpoints, 1 finish point). I now have to make an optimization for the distance calculation. I need to know which are the 7 fixes (including start fix and finish fix) for getting the largest distance possible.

I thought i can start with creating a N*N Matrix like this:

```
/// N*N matrix half-filled with the distances in kilometers between all points.

/// - N: Number of points
/// - X: Distance to every point (calculated with function above)
/// 
///  +-----------------------> column
/// Fix 1 | - - - - - - - - - - -
/// Fix 2 | X - - - - - - - - - -
/// Fix 3 | X X - - - - - - - - -
/// Fix 4 | X X X - - - - - - - -
/// Fix 5 | X X X X - - - - - - -
/// Fix 6 | X X X X X - - - - - -
/// Fix 7 | X X X X X X - - - - -
/// Fix 8 | X X X X X X X - - - -
/// Fix 9 | X X X X X X X X - - -
/// Fix 10| X X X X X X X X X - -
/// Fix 11| X X X X X X X X X X -
///  v
/// row
```

But now i dont know how i can evaluate the fixes i need.

In a second step, i also have to consider that the finish point have to be maximum 1000m lower than the first (starting) point. I heard something about Graph to find a solution, but i have no idea how to continue my work.

Thanks for help!